# Ubuntu CLI Drive removed

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, samba, command-line-interface, ntfs

I recently added a drive to my server. However, I check my computer this morning to find the drive doesn't show up on NTFS and I noticed that all folders and files were gone from that mount point on the server.

Note: I am using Ubuntu CLI 20.04.4 LTS || Image attached shows system logs.

[sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep sdb1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHkeS.png)

Comment: The system appears to have failed to mount that partition. Why? Who knows. Your logs doesn't show. Try running `mount /dev/sdb1` manually and see what error it spits out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Using testdisk to restore partition, not sure what happened, but that fixed my issue.